# Get children of an element that are not children of a container with a certain CSS class

Tags: jquery, nested, controls

I have nested control with same schema and based on passed control div ID, i want to select all item(".inner") except item in inner control.

```
 <div id="Main" class="outer">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="inner">inner1</div>

        <div id="Maininner" class="outer">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="inner">sub inner1</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function GetItem(id) {
        var item = $($(id).find(".item:first"));
        item.find(".inner:not(.outer .outer .inner)").each(function () {
            alert(id + ": " + $(this).html());
        });
    }

    if (typeof $ != "undefined") {
        $(function () {
            GetItem("#Main"); //expected output "inner1" , **working**


            GetItem("#Maininner"); //expected output "sub inner1" **not working**
        });
    };
</script>
```

I want to write common function to handle this scenarios. I tried using ":not", but its working only for some scenario.
Any better way to write code, which work for both scenario ?
NOTE: I can not change HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use children instead of find

i.e item.find(".inner:not(.outer .outer .inner)") instead use children(".inner") which will select direct children (immediate inner element) only

```
function GetItem(id) {
        var item = $($(id).find(".item:first"));

        item.children(".inner").each(function () {

            alert(id + ": " + $(this).html());
        });
    }
```

Comment: If "inner" div is not immediate children of "item", this logic is not going to work.